# If a jar is not placed in the libs folder the classes in jar file are not found

Tags: android

I am using a thirdparty jar file in my android project. When I add the jar to the build paths, via eclipse project -> properties -> java build path -> Libraries -> add external jar.

The project compiles fine until that line of code runs which uses any class from that jar and I get class not found exception at runtime and the program crashes.

I solved it by copying the third party jar file to the libs folder of my project. The class not found exception goes away.

Question:
Can someone please shed some light why this is required and why does it not just work with a reference from the project properties despite the fact it compiles fine.. Why do I have to explicitly copy it to libs folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I add the jar to the build paths, via eclipse project -> properties -> java build path -> Libraries -> add external jar.

That is not the proper procedure for use with the Android build tools.

> I  solved it by copying the third party jar file to the libs folder of my project. The class not found exception goes away.

Correct.

> Can someone please shed some light why this is required and why does it not just work with a reference from the project properties despite the fact it compiles fine.. Why do I have to explicitly copy it to libs folder ?

Because only the JARs in `libs/` are added to the APK file. The Java build path is pure a compile-time thing, not tied into Android's packaging of APK files.

Comment: Thanks, So if I understand correctly I should ONLY have my jar in libs are REMOVE it from the Java Build Path -> Libraries

Answer (score 0):

All the libraries in the folder “libs” are found by the Android Eclipse plugin and are added to the “Android Dependencies” item of the project.  A better illustration here
:http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17